# I'm trying to get started with LXC containers, and I'm getting a permissions problem on starting an unpriviledged container. How can I fix it?

Tags: lxc

I'm getting a permissions problem on starting an unpriviledged container.  How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by adding the LXC edgers PPA (might have been unnecessary) and `chmod +x ~/.local/share` ...
Shouldn't be a security risk, since they have to get in to home user permissions and home anyway to get there.

Comment: Which release was this? What are you using now? I'm currently trying to do the same and get different errors for each host release

Comment: 14.04, ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-lxc/daily/ubuntu, fully updated

Comment: Strange. Whatever I do, i get a "lxc_cgmanager - cgmanager.c:lxc_cgmanager_enter:698 - call to cgmanager_move_pid_sync failed: invalid request" tried both vivid or trusty, with and without updates repo, and with and without ppa

Comment: This string of tutorials should get you started https://www.stgraber.org/2013/12/20/lxc-1-0-blog-post-series/ - it's where I ran in to the unpriv container problem that caused this problem.

Comment: I read this posts already, but good to know that you succeeded using them. Here's what I did so far: http://askubuntu.com/questions/623789/problem-setting-up-a-user-space-lxc-container. Will recheck tonight if I missed something